# Does electrostatic discharge pose a threat for docking or capture in a 700km polar orbit?

Tags: spacecraft, low-earth-orbit

Is there any charging / ESD threat for a docking program at 700 km orbit?

Comment: I just voted to keep your question open as it looks interesting. That said, it was in the queue for close votes on the basis that it isn't clear what is being asked. Could you provide a little more context in the question please to spell out the direction you want it to go? For example only, are you looking specifically at differential charging between two vehicles brought into contact and how that could be mitigated?

Comment: Possibly related question: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/sparking-arcing-distance-between-two-spacecraft

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the orbit. Unlikely a risk at equatorial orbit, but at polar orbits this would be a significant issue. [Here is a good introduction](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9500.pdf) that talks about charging risks in different environments, and [another](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0906/0906.3884.pdf).

Summary: it's not to be ignored, but unlikely at risk at low latitudes in LEO region.  You might also look into [NASA-STD-4005 Low earth orbit spacecraft charging design standard](https://standards.nasa.gov/file/642/download?token=TTB1k_Ly)