# What generates static charge on the ISS?

Tags: iss, safety, spacecraft-charging

There are two plasma contactors on the ISS Z1 truss, designed to neutralize static electrical charge of the space station.

What generates static charge on a spacecraft? If it is picking up charge from the ionisphere, shouldn't it pick up an equal number of + and - ions?

Is the static charge a hazard to the ISS itself, or it only a hazard when docking with another spacecraft? Before docking, is there a “grounding” procedure to ensure both spacecraft are at the same potential?

Comment: The plasma contactors are turned on for EVA, but IIRC, not for docking. Related Q&As https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39366/6944  https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14163/6944

Comment: related: [How do spacecraft measure their own charge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20160/12102) (see especially @OrganicMarble's answer) and also [Do ISS crews have to worry about the ionosphere? Have hazards to EVAs or surface arcing/functional anomalies happened due to ionospheric charing?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49949/12102) and also [How did three 1.2 meter spheres and a Xe+ plasma contactor keep the Shuttle "grounded"? What did they look like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46616/12102)

Comment: Dont all spacecraft accumulate charge from solar flares ?  Same thing that causes Aurora must cause charge accumulation. There is a serious danger for upsets in the Computer with charge accumulation too in the transistors !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right; objects in space collect I+ and e- simultaneously. This results in a negative charge due to the rate at which these different particles are collected. Since electrons are far lighter than ions, they have much higher speeds at the same temperature, due to the [Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution). Therefore, they have a higher probability of being collected, thereby charging the object negative until its potential is high enough to repel further electrons.

With the following equation, one can calculate the potential of a spacecraft inside a space environment.

[image]

In general, this static charge can damage electrical components if it for example results in a discharge into an otherwise decoupled circuit. Some components are also quite sensitive to negative potentials across them.